# ¿Por qué el SelectedIndexChanged se carga al inicial la depuración?

Tags: c#

Me pasa eso, que quiero que salte ese evento cuándo hago un cambio dentro del comboBox y, sin embargo, se ejecuta al hacer la carga del formulario ¿Por qué pasa eso y como se evita?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque cuando agregas datos estas cambiando el seleccionado.

puedes poner

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(comboBox1.IsHandleCreated) // en un form tambien sirve this.IsHandleCreated
    {
       //No se ejecuta al inicio pero si cuando se cambia el seleccioando      
    }
    else
    {
        //se ejecuta al inicio        
    }
}
```